# WebRTC blank video on Firefox >= 90.0

Tags: reactjs, firefox, webrtc, sdp

I have a problem with a video from remote sdp not showing on Firefox on version >= 90.0 (does work on any other browser like Chrome, Opera, Edge). It works fine on version >=89.0.2 and i have no idea what causing this issue

## Firefox version 89.0.2

[image]

**Local sdp:**

```
v=0
o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-89.0.2 742372061482680230 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 AC:FD:FB:9D:BF:E7:1B:74:AC:A8:59:6B:F9:FE:B4:D0:15:EB:9C:9D:54:0A:3C:F0:A3:4B:39:32:88:92:AA:C9
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=sendrecv
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2/recvonly urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:csrc-audio-level
a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=fmtp:109 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=ice-pwd:acc210243a74aef9a612fb944269e3bd
a=ice-ufrag:ac64f811
a=mid:0
a=msid:{a4442659-b580-45d1-926b-855a5abb2ce5} {55d9c638-6580-41f7-a198-c4e4da48c0a9}
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000/1
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:1370367419 cname:{858121e4-b01a-410c-bc0f-2c7a46736d78}
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 120 124 121 125 126 127 97 98
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=sendrecv
a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:4 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:6/recvonly http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:7 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=fmtp:126 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1
a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1
a=fmtp:120 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=fmtp:124 apt=120
a=fmtp:121 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=fmtp:125 apt=121
a=fmtp:127 apt=126
a=fmtp:98 apt=97
a=ice-pwd:acc210243a74aef9a612fb944269e3bd
a=ice-ufrag:ac64f811
a=mid:1
a=msid:{a4442659-b580-45d1-926b-855a5abb2ce5} {b1684ca8-1a76-489a-ac8f-505d8db4a91a}
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:120 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:121 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:121 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:121 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:126 nack
a=rtcp-fb:126 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:126 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:126 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:126 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:97 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:97 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:97 transport-cc
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:124 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:121 VP9/90000
a=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:126 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:127 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:98 rtx/90000
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:945317264 cname:{858121e4-b01a-410c-bc0f-2c7a46736d78}
a=ssrc:662102401 cname:{858121e4-b01a-410c-bc0f-2c7a46736d78}
a=ssrc-group:FID 945317264 662102401

O 1 671 457 224 786 (+18 077 ms)

v=0
o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-89.0.2 742372061482680230 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=sendrecv
a=fingerprint:sha-256 AC:FD:FB:9D:BF:E7:1B:74:AC:A8:59:6B:F9:FE:B4:D0:15:EB:9C:9D:54:0A:3C:F0:A3:4B:39:32:88:92:AA:C9
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=audio 57307 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101
c=IN IP4 172.29.160.1
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122121471 10.100.1.109 57305 typ host
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 2122187007 192.168.1.22 57306 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 UDP 2122252543 172.29.160.1 57307 typ host
a=candidate:3 1 TCP 2105393407 10.100.1.109 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:4 1 TCP 2105458943 192.168.1.22 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:5 1 TCP 2105524479 172.29.160.1 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2122121470 10.100.1.109 57308 typ host
a=candidate:1 2 UDP 2122187006 192.168.1.22 57309 typ host
a=candidate:2 2 UDP 2122252542 172.29.160.1 57310 typ host
a=candidate:3 2 TCP 2105393406 10.100.1.109 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:4 2 TCP 2105458942 192.168.1.22 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:5 2 TCP 2105524478 172.29.160.1 9 typ host tcptype active
a=sendrecv
a=end-of-candidates
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2/recvonly urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:csrc-audio-level
a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=fmtp:109 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=ice-pwd:acc210243a74aef9a612fb944269e3bd
a=ice-ufrag:ac64f811
a=mid:0
a=msid:{a4442659-b580-45d1-926b-855a5abb2ce5} {55d9c638-6580-41f7-a198-c4e4da48c0a9}
a=rtcp:57310 IN IP4 172.29.160.1
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:1370367419 cname:{858121e4-b01a-410c-bc0f-2c7a46736d78}
m=video 57313 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 120 124 121 125 126 127 97 98
c=IN IP4 172.29.160.1
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122121471 10.100.1.109 57311 typ host
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 2122187007 192.168.1.22 57312 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 UDP 2122252543 172.29.160.1 57313 typ host
a=candidate:3 1 TCP 2105393407 10.100.1.109 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:4 1 TCP 2105458943 192.168.1.22 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:5 1 TCP 2105524479 172.29.160.1 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2122121470 10.100.1.109 57314 typ host
a=candidate:1 2 UDP 2122187006 192.168.1.22 57315 typ host
a=candidate:2 2 UDP 2122252542 172.29.160.1 57316 typ host
a=candidate:3 2 TCP 2105393406 10.100.1.109 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:4 2 TCP 2105458942 192.168.1.22 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:5 2 TCP 2105524478 172.29.160.1 9 typ host tcptype active
a=sendrecv
a=end-of-candidates
a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:4 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:6/recvonly http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:7 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=fmtp:126 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1
a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1
a=fmtp:120 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=fmtp:124 apt=120
a=fmtp:121 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=fmtp:125 apt=121
a=fmtp:127 apt=126
a=fmtp:98 apt=97
a=ice-pwd:acc210243a74aef9a612fb944269e3bd
a=ice-ufrag:ac64f811
a=mid:1
a=msid:{a4442659-b580-45d1-926b-855a5abb2ce5} {b1684ca8-1a76-489a-ac8f-505d8db4a91a}
a=rtcp:57316 IN IP4 172.29.160.1
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:120 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:121 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:121 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:121 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:126 nack
a=rtcp-fb:126 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:126 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:126 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:126 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:97 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:97 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:97 transport-cc
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:124 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:121 VP9/90000
a=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:126 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:127 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:98 rtx/90000
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:945317264 cname:{858121e4-b01a-410c-bc0f-2c7a46736d78}
a=ssrc:662102401 cname:{858121e4-b01a-410c-bc0f-2c7a46736d78}
a=ssrc-group:FID 945317264 662102401
```

**Remote sdp:**

```
v=0
o=- 123 1 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 93:70:63:FC:98:35:64:50:AB:07:B7:56:72:82:B8:6A:0E:58:D7:50:01:C0:D7:4A:01:86:C2:28:B1:AF:0C:E9
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic: WMS *
m=audio 1 RTP/SAVPF 8
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:1 1 udp 50 10.100.1.109 7070 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:1 2 udp 49 10.100.1.109 7070 typ host generation 0
a=inactive
a=ice-ufrag:wTURmjFPYaT2QrhY
a=ice-pwd:ALmcOQbLq5WnGMJ0QHZEBv1C
a=mid:0
a=msid:6bedb9d9-4a34-4fc5-a4e2-0228b1175ff3 21e020d5-0d34-404c-8d0f-c2176654ec8f
a=rtcp:2 IN 0.0.0.0 IP4
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=setup:passive
a=bundle-only
a=ssrc:2119652489 cname:baf88792-8306-49a1-9a52-bdeb340e7830
m=video 1 RTP/SAVPF 100
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:1 1 udp 50 10.100.1.109 7071 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:1 2 udp 49 10.100.1.109 7071 typ host generation 0
a=inactive
a=ice-ufrag:wTURmjFPYaT2QrhY
a=ice-pwd:ALmcOQbLq5WnGMJ0QHZEBv1C
a=mid:1
a=msid:6bedb9d9-4a34-4fc5-a4e2-0228b1175ff3 31f082d9-7b73-42cb-9ed1-09961329abd0
a=rtcp:2 IN 0.0.0.0 IP4
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=setup:passive
a=bundle-only
a=ssrc:4121478096 cname:baf88792-8306-49a1-9a52-bdeb340e7830

O 1 671 457 224 796 (+18 087 ms)

v=0
o=- 123 1 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 93:70:63:FC:98:35:64:50:AB:07:B7:56:72:82:B8:6A:0E:58:D7:50:01:C0:D7:4A:01:86:C2:28:B1:AF:0C:E9
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic: WMS *
m=audio 1 RTP/SAVPF 8
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:1 1 udp 50 10.100.1.109 7070 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:1 2 udp 49 10.100.1.109 7070 typ host generation 0
a=sendrecv
a=ice-ufrag:wTURmjFPYaT2QrhY
a=ice-pwd:ALmcOQbLq5WnGMJ0QHZEBv1C
a=mid:0
a=msid:6d6a5d67-fc98-487a-ae11-feadf0a83550_2 694408ad-38a9-4370-9bf7-a6ddd358740e
a=rtcp:2 IN 0.0.0.0 IP4
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=setup:passive
a=bundle-only
a=ssrc:1888215093 cname:xpWB66DXxxbEXrg9
m=video 1 RTP/SAVPF 100
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:1 1 udp 50 10.100.1.109 7071 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:1 2 udp 49 10.100.1.109 7071 typ host generation 0
a=sendrecv
a=ice-ufrag:wTURmjFPYaT2QrhY
a=ice-pwd:ALmcOQbLq5WnGMJ0QHZEBv1C
a=mid:1
a=msid:6d6a5d67-fc98-487a-ae11-feadf0a83550_2 54387bb6-ba0c-44ba-9811-f7d633371968
a=rtcp:2 IN 0.0.0.0 IP4
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=setup:passive
a=bundle-only
a=ssrc:1079489670 cname:G9MLJqqUtxfIQKyH
```

**RTP Stats:**

[image]

## Firefox version >= 90.0

[image]

Local sdp:

```
v=0
o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-90.0 8353154283338443297 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 C1:21:34:75:76:EE:AA:32:AD:D9:BB:C1:DD:7B:BD:82:1E:E3:85:8A:D1:A4:73:1E:35:76:40:16:54:D6:EB:DB
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=sendrecv
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2/recvonly urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:csrc-audio-level
a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=fmtp:109 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=ice-pwd:8118e393f3952040e0060e800c17dbc2
a=ice-ufrag:b515cfad
a=mid:0
a=msid:{d4ef79cc-6ab6-4464-b581-ece2c3fbf1e0} {94e2d2bc-2124-4c93-87e2-ea9bd0e10945}
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000/1
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:2400082512 cname:{ca38a686-634a-477e-89a3-16f4b00ce5c6}
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 120 124 121 125 126 127 97 98
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=sendrecv
a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:4 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:6/recvonly http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:7 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=fmtp:126 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1
a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1
a=fmtp:120 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=fmtp:124 apt=120
a=fmtp:121 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=fmtp:125 apt=121
a=fmtp:127 apt=126
a=fmtp:98 apt=97
a=ice-pwd:8118e393f3952040e0060e800c17dbc2
a=ice-ufrag:b515cfad
a=mid:1
a=msid:{d4ef79cc-6ab6-4464-b581-ece2c3fbf1e0} {ee4a3916-55a7-4992-8134-c81ac8cea572}
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:120 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:121 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:121 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:121 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:126 nack
a=rtcp-fb:126 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:126 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:126 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:126 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:97 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:97 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:97 transport-cc
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:124 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:121 VP9/90000
a=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:126 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:127 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:98 rtx/90000
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:4074242173 cname:{ca38a686-634a-477e-89a3-16f4b00ce5c6}
a=ssrc:3652788950 cname:{ca38a686-634a-477e-89a3-16f4b00ce5c6}
a=ssrc-group:FID 4074242173 3652788950

O 1 671 457 637 509 (+15 993 ms)

v=0
o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-90.0 8353154283338443297 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=sendrecv
a=fingerprint:sha-256 C1:21:34:75:76:EE:AA:32:AD:D9:BB:C1:DD:7B:BD:82:1E:E3:85:8A:D1:A4:73:1E:35:76:40:16:54:D6:EB:DB
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=audio 50163 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101
c=IN IP4 172.29.160.1
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122121471 10.100.1.109 50161 typ host
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 2122187007 192.168.1.22 50162 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 UDP 2122252543 172.29.160.1 50163 typ host
a=candidate:3 1 TCP 2105393407 10.100.1.109 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:4 1 TCP 2105458943 192.168.1.22 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:5 1 TCP 2105524479 172.29.160.1 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2122121470 10.100.1.109 50164 typ host
a=candidate:1 2 UDP 2122187006 192.168.1.22 50165 typ host
a=candidate:2 2 UDP 2122252542 172.29.160.1 50166 typ host
a=candidate:3 2 TCP 2105393406 10.100.1.109 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:4 2 TCP 2105458942 192.168.1.22 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:5 2 TCP 2105524478 172.29.160.1 9 typ host tcptype active
a=sendrecv
a=end-of-candidates
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2/recvonly urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:csrc-audio-level
a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=fmtp:109 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=ice-pwd:8118e393f3952040e0060e800c17dbc2
a=ice-ufrag:b515cfad
a=mid:0
a=msid:{d4ef79cc-6ab6-4464-b581-ece2c3fbf1e0} {94e2d2bc-2124-4c93-87e2-ea9bd0e10945}
a=rtcp:50166 IN IP4 172.29.160.1
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:2400082512 cname:{ca38a686-634a-477e-89a3-16f4b00ce5c6}
m=video 50169 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 120 124 121 125 126 127 97 98
c=IN IP4 172.29.160.1
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122121471 10.100.1.109 50167 typ host
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 2122187007 192.168.1.22 50168 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 UDP 2122252543 172.29.160.1 50169 typ host
a=candidate:3 1 TCP 2105393407 10.100.1.109 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:4 1 TCP 2105458943 192.168.1.22 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:5 1 TCP 2105524479 172.29.160.1 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2122121470 10.100.1.109 50170 typ host
a=candidate:1 2 UDP 2122187006 192.168.1.22 50171 typ host
a=candidate:2 2 UDP 2122252542 172.29.160.1 50172 typ host
a=candidate:3 2 TCP 2105393406 10.100.1.109 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:4 2 TCP 2105458942 192.168.1.22 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:5 2 TCP 2105524478 172.29.160.1 9 typ host tcptype active
a=sendrecv
a=end-of-candidates
a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:4 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:6/recvonly http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:7 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=fmtp:126 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1
a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1
a=fmtp:120 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=fmtp:124 apt=120
a=fmtp:121 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=fmtp:125 apt=121
a=fmtp:127 apt=126
a=fmtp:98 apt=97
a=ice-pwd:8118e393f3952040e0060e800c17dbc2
a=ice-ufrag:b515cfad
a=mid:1
a=msid:{d4ef79cc-6ab6-4464-b581-ece2c3fbf1e0} {ee4a3916-55a7-4992-8134-c81ac8cea572}
a=rtcp:50172 IN IP4 172.29.160.1
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:120 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:121 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:121 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:121 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:126 nack
a=rtcp-fb:126 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:126 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:126 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:126 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:97 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:97 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:97 transport-cc
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:124 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:121 VP9/90000
a=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:126 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:127 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:98 rtx/90000
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:4074242173 cname:{ca38a686-634a-477e-89a3-16f4b00ce5c6}
a=ssrc:3652788950 cname:{ca38a686-634a-477e-89a3-16f4b00ce5c6}
a=ssrc-group:FID 4074242173 3652788950
```

Remote sdp:

```
v=0
o=- 123 1 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 93:70:63:FC:98:35:64:50:AB:07:B7:56:72:82:B8:6A:0E:58:D7:50:01:C0:D7:4A:01:86:C2:28:B1:AF:0C:E9
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic: WMS *
m=audio 1 RTP/SAVPF 8
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:1 1 udp 50 10.100.1.109 7074 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:1 2 udp 49 10.100.1.109 7074 typ host generation 0
a=inactive
a=ice-ufrag:5uVuNDrpZIRuqFnv
a=ice-pwd:2gTsLDmpv3Rc0SJDsc3MydjT
a=mid:0
a=msid:77975ac5-83a8-41d3-95d6-28330784cf7e 5cabb463-4897-47a7-b216-3eb503e7a7f1
a=rtcp:2 IN 0.0.0.0 IP4
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=setup:passive
a=bundle-only
a=ssrc:141019633 cname:484ad88b-f66d-4478-9efc-4274dec179c3
m=video 1 RTP/SAVPF 100
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:1 1 udp 50 10.100.1.109 7075 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:1 2 udp 49 10.100.1.109 7075 typ host generation 0
a=inactive
a=ice-ufrag:5uVuNDrpZIRuqFnv
a=ice-pwd:2gTsLDmpv3Rc0SJDsc3MydjT
a=mid:1
a=msid:77975ac5-83a8-41d3-95d6-28330784cf7e ea40ec6c-8f23-4876-8603-4e88e4685c93
a=rtcp:2 IN 0.0.0.0 IP4
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=setup:passive
a=bundle-only
a=ssrc:1824197586 cname:484ad88b-f66d-4478-9efc-4274dec179c3

O 1 671 457 637 515 (+15 999 ms)

v=0
o=- 123 1 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 93:70:63:FC:98:35:64:50:AB:07:B7:56:72:82:B8:6A:0E:58:D7:50:01:C0:D7:4A:01:86:C2:28:B1:AF:0C:E9
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic: WMS *
m=audio 1 RTP/SAVPF 8
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:1 1 udp 50 10.100.1.109 7074 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:1 2 udp 49 10.100.1.109 7074 typ host generation 0
a=sendrecv
a=ice-ufrag:5uVuNDrpZIRuqFnv
a=ice-pwd:2gTsLDmpv3Rc0SJDsc3MydjT
a=mid:0
a=msid:6d6a5d67-fc98-487a-ae11-feadf0a83550_3 259c9f41-df1a-4a0a-99bb-865925751627
a=rtcp:2 IN 0.0.0.0 IP4
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=setup:passive
a=bundle-only
a=ssrc:365022300 cname:QylQ1HGpor9omS0z
m=video 1 RTP/SAVPF 100
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:1 1 udp 50 10.100.1.109 7075 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:1 2 udp 49 10.100.1.109 7075 typ host generation 0
a=sendrecv
a=ice-ufrag:5uVuNDrpZIRuqFnv
a=ice-pwd:2gTsLDmpv3Rc0SJDsc3MydjT
a=mid:1
a=msid:6d6a5d67-fc98-487a-ae11-feadf0a83550_3 c0827912-56ab-4aaf-a97c-eb400dba9ad0
a=rtcp:2 IN 0.0.0.0 IP4
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=setup:passive
a=bundle-only
a=ssrc:3945247179 cname:9Tn424ILJFMaRaPw
```

RTP Stats:

[image]

I have tried changing SDP. I compared my generated sdp to sdp from this website https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/munge-sdp/

I listened to packets using wireshark and everything seems fine, but video does not show up.

Feel free to ask for more information. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I was sending payload in my sdp a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000, but firefox >=90.0 supports vp8 in version 120 as u can see in local sdp a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).